# How to create a column reference dynamically?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have DataFrame `df` with the following structure:

```
root
 |-- author: array (nullable = true)
 |    |-- element: integer (containsNull = true)
 |-- client: array (nullable = true)
 |    |-- element: integer (containsNull = true)
 |-- outbound_link: array (nullable = true)
 |    |-- element: string (containsNull = true)
 |-- url: string (nullable = true)
```

I run this code:

```
val sourceField = "outbound_link" // set automatically
val targetField = "url"           // set automatically
val nodeId = "client"             // set automatically

val result = df.as("df1").join(df.as("df2"),
        $"df1."+sourceField === $"df2."+targetField
        ).groupBy(
          ($"df1."+nodeId).as("nodeId_1"),
          ($"df2."+nodeId).as("nodeId_2")
        )
        .agg(
          count("*") as "value", max($"df1."+timestampField) as "timestamp"
        )
        .toDF("source", "target", "value", "timestamp")
```

But I get the error:

```
Exception in thread "main" org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: syntax error in attribute name: df1.;
```

For some reason, the variables `sourceField` and `targetField` are not visible inside `join`operation. These variables are not empty and contain the names of fields. I must use variables because I define them automatically in a previous step of code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An interesting case indeed. Look at `$"df1."+sourceField` and think about when `$"df1."` gets converted to a `Column` versus the concatenation of `"df1."+sourceField`.

```
scala> val sourceField = "id"
sourceField: String = id

scala> $"df1."+sourceField
org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: syntax error in attribute name: df1.;
  at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.analysis.UnresolvedAttribute$.e$1(unresolved.scala:151)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.analysis.UnresolvedAttribute$.parseAttributeName(unresolved.scala:170)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.analysis.UnresolvedAttribute$.quotedString(unresolved.scala:142)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.Column.<init>(Column.scala:137)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.ColumnName.<init>(Column.scala:1203)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.SQLImplicits$StringToColumn.$(SQLImplicits.scala:45)
  ... 55 elided
```

Replace `$"df1."+sourceField` to use `col` or `column` functions and you should be fine.

```
scala> col(s"df1.$sourceField")
res7: org.apache.spark.sql.Column = df1.id
```